# Passing ajax data item to the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajax function as below and I want to send item to the find function

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item) {
      html += '<div class="tileBlock"><img src="/PublishingImages/' + item.Title + '" alt="' + item.To[city] + '" /><br>';
      html += '<div class="blockCol1 greyLabel">' + item.To[city] + '</div><div class="blockCol2 fareTxt">' + item.Cost + '&nbsp;' + item.From.Currency + '</div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
      html += '<div class=" blockCol3 smallTxt">' + item.Class + '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' + item.Trip + '</div><br><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
      html += '<div class="btnHolder"><input name="button" type="button" onclick="javascript:Find(' + item + ')" class="searchBtn wth150" h ref"#" value="Book now" /></div></div>';
    });
    $("#dvPromotion").empty();
    $("#dvPromotion").html(html);
  }
});
```

My find function

```
function Find(item) {
        console.dir(item)
    }
```

But it is not working, can somebody guide me

**Update**

MY JSON

```
{"results":[{"__metadata":{"id":"Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(2)","uri":"http://webdev.kuwaitairways.com:8080/_api/Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(2)","etag":"\"4\"","type":"SP.Data.PromotionListItem"},"From":{"__metadata":{"id":"dffa96c4-1b04-419a-991c-0913640152c4","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Kuwait","Currency":"KWD"},"To":{"__metadata":{"id":"4302885c-0545-4cbf-9771-8cea409b4d98","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Abu Dhabi"},"Title":"abuDhabi.jpg","Class":"economy","Trip":"RT","Cost":"60"},{"__metadata":{"id":"Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(3)","uri":"http://webdev.kuwaitairways.com:8080/_api/Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(3)","etag":"\"5\"","type":"SP.Data.PromotionListItem"},"From":{"__metadata":{"id":"f57e53d4-d576-4be7-a141-2357c4287013","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Kuwait","Currency":"KWD"},"To":{"__metadata":{"id":"383e7bfd-cf17-4fc4-b115-03ceaeb71db9","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Bangalore"},"Title":"banglore.jpg","Class":"economy","Trip":"RT","Cost":"99"},{"__metadata":{"id":"Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(4)","uri":"http://webdev.kuwaitairways.com:8080/_api/Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(4)","etag":"\"5\"","type":"SP.Data.PromotionListItem"},"From":{"__metadata":{"id":"09ab5da0-8c92-437c-974d-111f31f9cb51","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Kuwait","Currency":"KWD"},"To":{"__metadata":{"id":"24a99e65-fef4-452d-9879-9110b4b2e1bf","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Beirut"},"Title":"beirut.jpg","Class":"economy","Trip":"RT","Cost":"56"},{"__metadata":{"id":"Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(5)","uri":"http://webdev.kuwaitairways.com:8080/_api/Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(5)","etag":"\"5\"","type":"SP.Data.PromotionListItem"},"From":{"__metadata":{"id":"8c9fb3d0-1f9e-44c7-9921-bb5fa63a929f","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Kuwait","Currency":"KWD"},"To":{"__metadata":{"id":"efb0db77-3dfd-42d7-9bb5-3b9733ac68be","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Cairo"},"Title":"cairo.jpg","Class":"economy","Trip":"RT","Cost":"79"},{"__metadata":{"id":"Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(6)","uri":"http://webdev.kuwaitairways.com:8080/_api/Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(6)","etag":"\"5\"","type":"SP.Data.PromotionListItem"},"From":{"__metadata":{"id":"70a824cc-a12f-4d6f-ba58-7f67a9ac439b","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Kuwait","Currency":"KWD"},"To":{"__metadata":{"id":"4bcb5bd1-e49e-430d-9091-5edda2d6ccbc","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Colombo"},"Title":"colombo.jpg","Class":"economy","Trip":"RT","Cost":"92"},{"__metadata":{"id":"Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(7)","uri":"http://webdev.kuwaitairways.com:8080/_api/Web/Lists(guid'6aaed852-b5cf-4c6a-8066-9d1b85fb52f4')/Items(7)","etag":"\"5\"","type":"SP.Data.PromotionListItem"},"From":{"__metadata":{"id":"48314626-626e-433d-bea2-bb404b525629","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Kuwait","Currency":"KWD"},"To":{"__metadata":{"id":"77511f79-1dd1-466c-a66c-06a4c3bd6946","type":"SP.Data.StationsListItem"},"Title":"Delhi"},"Title":"delhi.jpg","Class":"economy","Trip":"RT","Cost":"88"}]}
```

Comment: Any errors you seeing in console?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Comment: Which line of code?

Comment: <input name="button" type="button" onclick="javascript:Find(' + item + ')" class="searchBtn wth150" h ref"#" value="Book now" />

Comment: What happens if you comment out all the `html +=` and do a `console.log(item);` ?

Comment: looks like I am not passing parameter properly. Kindly help me

Comment: At this line, you can see a beautiful `h ref"#"` instead of `href="#"` :D

Comment: Can you post the whole JSON in the question?

Comment: I added my json

Comment: check your console check if there's a `typeof` error

Comment: `<div class="btnHolder"><input name="button" type="button" onclick="javascript:Find(' + item + ')" class="searchBtn wth150" h ref"#" value="Book now" /></div></div>';` this part of the code looks wierd at `h ref"#"`. Shouldn't this be `href="#"`?

Comment: @Milind, see my answer.

Comment: @Nomeaning25 sorry i removed href it was typo mistake

Comment: @Milind Are you still getting same error?

Comment: @Nomeaning25 yes still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will work with making minimum changes to your existing code.
Basically it will involve two things:

1. Attaching custom data attributes to your dynamically generated buttons Ref: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/
2. Attaching an event handler to a parent element of your buttons with your buttons class-name as selector context Ref: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Please see the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/y0bafvvt/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1mkxw',
  method: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    let html;
    $.each(data.results, function (i, item) {
      html += '<div class="tileBlock"><img src="/PublishingImages/' + item.Title + '" alt="' + item.To.Title + '" /><br>';
      html += '<div class="blockCol1 greyLabel">' + item.To.Title + '</div><div class="blockCol2 fareTxt">' + item.Cost + '&nbsp;' + item.From.Currency + '</div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
      html += '<div class=" blockCol3 smallTxt">' + item.Class + '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' + item.Trip + '</div><br><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
      html += '<div class="btnHolder"><input name="button" class="btn-finder" type="button" data-item="' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item)) + '" class="searchBtn wth150" href="#" value="Book now" /></div></div>';
    });
    $("#dvPromotion").empty();
    $("#dvPromotion").html(html);
  }
});

// Attach an event listener to the document element (or any other parent element of your buttons)
$(document).on('click', '.btn-finder', function() {
  console.dir(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($(this).data('item'))));
});
```

Comment: I am getting below error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 497 of the JSON data
 

console.dir(JSON.parse($(this).data('item')));

Comment: It have error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 497 of the JSON data
 

console.dir(JSON.parse($(this).data('item')));

Comment: @Milind, You are bound to get these type of error now as well as in future if are going to use this approach

Comment: You don't need to use `JSON.parse()` as `$(this).data('item')` tries to convert object in appropriate data-type internally and it returns that

Comment: @Milind you might also need to apply some changes in the way you are accessing you `item`'s properties as suggested in @lonut's answer

Comment: @Milind working solution has been made available at JSFiddle. Please check.

Comment: @sid-m Thank you its work as needed but I just wanted to know why you put closing ) in data-item.

Comment: @Milind ohh, it was a typo. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create HTML using jQuery method, Using this you can use `.data(key, value)` to store arbitrary data with element which will be stored in internal cache.

As you are generating elements dynamically, use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach. In the event handler you can fetch the data using `.data(key)`

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#dvPromotion").empty();

        $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {
            var div = $('<div />', {
                    "class": "tileBlock"
                }).append($('<img />', {
                    src: "/PublishingImages/" + item.Title,
                    alt: item.To[city]
                }))
                .append($('<br />'));

            //Other elements

            var input = $('<input />', {
                name: "button",
                type: "button",
                class: "searchBtn wth150",
                value: "Book now"
            })

            input.data('item', item);
            div.append(input);
            $("#dvPromotion").append(div);
        });
    }
});

//Bind event handler
$("#dvPromotion").on('click', '.searchBtn', function() {
    var iten = $(this).data('item');
})
```

Comment: i don't want to change my whole code. Is it not possible for my existing code

Comment: @Milind, You are creating HTML using string concatenation. it is quotes mess and I don't recommend it. Using jQuery way of creating HTML is quite maintable and easy to understand. Since `item` is complex JSON object You can try `"onclick="javascript:Find(' + JSON.stringify(item) + ')""`

Answer (score 0):

You had some mistakes in your code, like `item.To[city]` who should be `item.To.Title`, also `data.d.results` should be `data.results`. Corrected them.

Also the problem why you are getting that error `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list` is because `Find([object Object])` is not valid syntax.

So instead of `javascript:Find(" + item + ")` you would use `javascript:Find(" + item.From.Title + ")` for example.

A [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cr6akv5g/), and the code who you can run it from here too:

```js
var html = '';
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1mkxw',
  method: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.results, function (i, item) {
      html += '<div class="tileBlock"><img src="/PublishingImages/' + item.Title + '" alt="' + item.To.Title + '" /><br>';
      html += '<div class="blockCol1 greyLabel">' + item.To.Title + '</div><div class="blockCol2 fareTxt">' + item.Cost + '&nbsp;' + item.From.Currency + '</div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
      html += '<div class=" blockCol3 smallTxt">' + item.Class + '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' + item.Trip + '</div><br><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
      html += "<div class='btnHolder'><input name='button' type='button' onclick='javascript:Find(" + item + ")' class='searchBtn wth150' href='#' value='Book now' /></div></div>";
    });
    $("#dvPromotion").empty();
    $("#dvPromotion").html(html);
  }
});

function Find(item) {
  console.dir(item)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dvPromotion'>

</div>
```

Comment: I know. Working on that and I will improve my answer.

Comment: I used his JSON. So I think it's more than correct.